# javascript regular expression - valid characters and a group anywhere in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need help coming up with a regular expression to validate characters and multiple groups that can occur anywhere within a string.

Basically this is for a file name that can contain specific placeholder patterns.  So valid characters are alpha-numeric and .(period).  The patterns are %d4% and %t7%.  So % is not valid by itself, but has to be part of these specific patterns.

So some valid examples would be:

```
test.file.D%d4%
%d4%.test.file
D%d4%.T%t7%.test.%t7%file.%d4%.txt
```

Invalid examples would be:

```
t%est.file.D%d4%
%d4%.te%st.file
D%d4%.T%t7%.te%st.%t7%file.%d4%.txt
```

Comment: Can you post your current regex? What didn't work?

Comment: "alpha-numeric and " Something is missing there.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have anything that comes close as far as I can tell.  Just for matching the group I have (%(d4)|(t7)%)*.  Just to validate the characters I have ^[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+$  But putting them together doesn't work.  so ^[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+$(%(d4)|(t7)%)* will not match on test.file.%t7% which should be valid.

Comment: Of course putting them together like that won't work. The idea is that  you familiarize yourself with regex before asking. This just looks like a "gimme dat regex" question. Regex are simple so people usually take 1 min to answer, but you'd get more answers if you show some effort.

Comment: thanks elclanrs, you are so helpful.  You know in all the time I put into this today, I never thought to read the documentation or try several options.  Thanks so much for your insight and I consider myself humbled before your brilliance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this pattern:

```
/^([a-z0-9.]|%(d4|t7)%)+$/i
```

You can test it [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gim&regex=%5E(%5Ba-z0-9.%5D%7C%25(d4%7Ct7)%25)%2B%24&input=test.file.D%25d4%25%0A%25d4%25.test.file%0AD%25d4%25.T%25t7%25.test.%25t7%25file.%25d4%25.txt%0A%0At%25est.file.D%25d4%25%0A%25d4%25.te%25st.file%0AD%25d4%25.T%25t7%25.te%25st.%25t7%25file.%25d4%25.txt).

Hopefully the following diagram will illustrate precisely how this works:

[image: regexpr]

Comment: Sometimes it's hard to see the obvious